# modx Api MiniShop2 для создания категорий и товаров

Tags: api, modx, minishop2

Я бы хотел спросить. Как в minishop2 создать категорию товара и прописать у неё: родительскую категорию товаров если она есть (у меня иерархическая структура категорий товаров), название категории. Также получение id категории по её названию. Может кто ссылку нормальную даст на документацию по API minishop2?
Всё что я умел нарыть это: $modx->newObject(«msCategory»); $obj->fromArray(); $obj->save();
А что нужно задавать в $obj->fromArray() — я не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Вот ответ на этот вопрос. Код рабочий.

```
function createNewCategory($parentCategoryId, $categoryName){
global $modx;

$alias = md5('category_alias'.rand(1,10000).rand(1,10000).rand(1,10000));

$params = array('class_key' => 'msCategory', 'name'=>$categoryName, 'pagetitle'=>$categoryName, 'parent'=>$parentCategoryId,'published'=>true, 'template'=>8, 'alias'=>$alias);
$q = $modx->newObject('modResource', $params);




$q->save();
return $q->id;
}
```